# .focus() not working from within .focus() event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am unable to successfully use .focus() from the focusout event, on the same element. I've tried it with a setTimeout as well. Any ideas?

```
    $(control).focusout(function (e) {
                    if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
                        for (var ii = 0; ii < sampleDTOList.length; ii++) {
                            if (sampleDTOList[ii]["controlId"] == $(this).attr("id")) {
                                if ($(this).val() <= parseFloat(sampleDTOList[ii]["maxValue"]) && $(this).val() >= parseFloat(sampleDTOList[ii]["minValue"])) {
                                    sampleDTOList[ii]["value"] = $(this).val();
                                    RunRulesOnSample(sampleDTOList[ii]);
                                    return;
                                }
                                else {
                                    $(this).val("");
                                    alert("You must enter a value between " + sampleDTOList[ii]["minValue"] + " and " + sampleDTOList[ii]["maxValue"] + ".");
                                    $(this).focus();
                                    return;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Comment: on focus out you want to focus again based on condition!!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible to directly call the focus function on a focusout event handler. Also, you can't say preventDefault() on the event object, because the focusout event is not cancelable.

But it seems you can use the setTimeout function:

```
$('#foo').focusout(function(e) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#foo').focus();
    }, 10);
});
```

Check out this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BgQm6/5/).

And you can also find a workaround which uses the `mousedown` event [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14613804/is-there-a-way-to-use-preventdefault-event-with-focusout-if-not-why)